# linking two ipysheets in a jupyter notebook to visualise with voila

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, spreadsheet

I would like to use ipysheets and ipywidgets to generate a web-alike user interface using voila in a jupyter notebook.

This is a super powerful tool to very fast create user interfaces for fast user interaction without having to resort to web pages, i.e. servers, django, web frames and the like.

I am trying to link cells of two ipysheets, one for input data and other one for output data.
The content of the output data sheet should be updated on the fly every time there is a change in the input data (in this case as example by clicking the check boxes).

```
from ipysheet import *
import ipywidgets as widgets
import ipysheet
import pandas as pd

# example dataframe with check boxes, (including booleans)
DF_input = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[False,False,False],'b':[False,False,False]})
sheet_input = ipysheet.sheet(from_dataframe(DF_input))

# Output dataframe has as many columns as input dataframe but only one row
DF_m = pd.DataFrame(data={'m1':['non'],'m2':['non']})               
sheet_m = ipysheet.sheet(from_dataframe(DF_m))

# I try here to pass the cells of the current ipysheet to cell_m1 and cell_m2
cell_m1 = ipysheet.cell(0, 1)
cell_m2 = ipysheet.cell(0, 2)

I would like that this function runs every time there is a change in the Input sheet.
def calculate(change):
    mydf = to_dataframe(sheet_input)
    cell_m1.value = mydf.loc[:,'a'].any()
    cell_m2.value = mydf.loc[:,'b'].any()

# I want that the cells of the second sheet observe the changes. 
# I want to call the function calculate everytime there is a change
cell_m1.observe(calculate, 'value')
cell_m2.observe(calculate, 'value')

widgets.VBox([sheet_input,sheet_m])
```

This is the result:

[image]

When trying to click the check boxes strange things happen:

[image]

What I ultimately want to do is link cells of the second sheet_m to the values of first sheet_input. The function calculate has to get all the table of sheet_input make some calculations and fill in values in sheet_m.

What did I do:
I read many times the documentation of ipysheets and above all the observe function.
https://readthedocs.org/projects/ipysheet/downloads/pdf/latest/

Some help would be nice.